# Rails 4: Customizing email_field_tag helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, helper

How to customize with css and translate the default message for email_field_tag, "class:" is not working and I can't find the correct entry in locales yml files.

Answer (score 1):

Translate? As if have it in different languages?

**en.yml**

```
en:
  views:
    layout:
      placeholders: 'Your E-mail Address'
```

And the field:

```
<%= email_field_tag :email, "", class: "yeah", :placeholder => t('views.layout.placeholders') %>
```

You can customize the placeholder "route" also.